# Whats the difference between ServiceStack.OrmLite packages and .Signed version?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

When download the packages in Visual Studio there are two version of the same packages for ServiceStack.

ServiceStack
ServiceStack Signed

What is the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack NuGet packages with a **.Signed** Suffix are strong-named, where other ServiceStack packages are not Strong named by default except for `ServiceStack.Interfaces` which is both Strong-Named and a pure PCL library for maximum accessibility.

The ServiceStack download page maintains the list of [available Signed packages](https://servicestack.net/download#signed).